# Merging Excel files on a keyfield

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, merge

Using the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/366647/merge-two-excel-files-using-a-common-column) as my starting point, I have a slightly different scenario that I'm stuck on.

**Consider:**

**File 1:** Incident# (key), foo1, foo2, foo3

**File 2:** Incident# (key), status, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6

**Other considerations:**

An incident number may appear in File 1, but not File 2 (no status on incident; assumed open and unassigned).

An incident number may appear in File 2, but not File 1 (an incident that opened prior to the data's scope, but resolved after.

Right now, I'm tring to create
**File 3:** by doing a `VLOOKUP` on Incident#, and I would like the following fields to appear, based on the following rules.

1. Incident# (if incident# is in File 1 but NOT file 2, populate status
   with 'pending'. if incident# is in File 2 but NOT file 1, append the
   record to the file.
2. foo1
3. foo2
4. foo3 (if `status` is not null, then UPDATE the value for foo3 to the value from File2
5. foo4
6. foo5
7. foo6

However, because my result file is based on comparing values from BOTH sets of keyfields (not jsut a 'one-way' lookup), I fear I'll end up with Circular References and inaccurate data.

Any hints on how to make this happen?

Comment: This can be difficult to automate 100%, but if you’re willing to do 5% of the work, you can automate the rest.  See [this question](http://superuser.com/q/479472/150988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Scott proposed a great solution (which I've got bookmarked 'cause I know I'll need it in the future...), we ended up being able to complete this with 'VLOOKUP' because the user suddenly "discovered" additional data columns in the excel files AND changed their requirements.